Unable to run a .sh file. X Error of failed request: BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
`X Error of failed request:  BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length error)
  Major opcode of failed request:  18 (X_ChangeProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  598
  Current serial number in output stream:  598

How to proceed?
OS - Ubuntu 24.04
This error was first observed after upgrading the OS 3 days ago.
Tried looking up solutions in StackOverflow but none are working.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd like to run a .sh file. But when I type in ./ after opening the terminal in the folder with the file, I'm shown the error stated above.
The file is not corrupt, I'm just not able to run it.
